# Openpyxl. Max_columns giving error

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl-2.4.0-b1 and Python version 34. Following is my code:

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

```
filename= str(input('Please  enter the filename name, with the entire path and extension: '))
wb  = load_workbook(filename)
ws  = wb.worksheets[0]
row_main = 1

#Main Program starts here. Loop for the entire file
print ('Col =', ws.max_column())
while (row_main <(ws.max_row())): #Process rows for each column
    print ('ROW =', row_main)
    row_main += 1
```

It runs into an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print ('Col =', ws.max_column())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I can't use *get* because it has been deprecated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't write code like this because it works against the published API. Calling `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column` often will be very slow as they require openpyxl to calculate the size of the worksheet every time. This is why we provide the methods for working with rows and columns.

Answer (score 5):

As `max_column` is `property`, so just use the name to get its value:

```
print('Col =', ws.max_column)
```

Also apply on `max_row`:

```
while (row_main < ws.max_row):
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Pandas library

```
import pandas as pd


name_of_file =  "test.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(name_of_file)

total_rows = len(data)
total_columns = len(data.columns)

print(total_rows, total_columns)
```